# How can I disable in jdk RSA algorithm with keySize 1024?

Tags: java, security, ssl

**ENVIRONMENT:** Java version `1.8.0_121`

**SITUATION:**

Created Certificate with RSA 1024.
Enabled SSL and my web site available from https.

**TASK:**
I wanted to disable site availability for RSA 1024.

**ACTION:**

I modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=RSA keySize < 2048` then from browser called web site -> available and RSA was not disabled.

I modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=RSA` then from browser called web site  ->  not available and RSA was disabled(got an error message see **RESULT**).

**RESULT**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1478)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeWrap(SecureNioChannel.java:424)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1411)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I disable RSA via keySize constraint?

Comment: Wow, that was difficult to read. So very many typos!!! "feom"? "foe"? "modidied"? "swema"?

Comment: Sorry for that was written by phone night time.

Answer (score 3):

**REVISED:** Sorry, I somehow thought this was for client side and (thus) cert validation; looking back you didn't say that, but it was only the trace from Tomcat (server!) that made me realize this. After further *correct* investigation:

The syntax, explained in the comments next to where you editted and already in the default for all Oracle j8+ releases (and some j7) is `RSA keySize < 2048` or `RSA keySize <= 1024` -- BUT the keySize part only works for *cert (path) validation* which applies to actual, specific certs and is normally done on SSL/TLS client but not SSL/TLS server.

JSSE uses both `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` AND `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` to filter the list of ciphersuites used (and now looking at it, I'm not sure why; an algorithm being unsuitable for cert validation doesn't automatically make it unsuitable for TLS) but ciphersuite filtering only works on entries for the whole algorithm not entries for a specific keySize, since keySize is not reliably known at the time ciphersuite filtering is done. (A client has no clue at all; a server can have more than one key&chain, and selection may use the SNI extension in ClientHello. Selection could also be based on client's supported_curves, which OpenSSL does, but AFAICS JSSE doesn't, at least in the default `X509KeyManagerImpl`.)

Thus although setting `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=alg` does have the effect of disabling all {alg} ciphersuites, setting `alg keySize...` does not. I don't think you can have this checked automatically, you'll just have to not configure a key (and its cert/chain) that is too weak.

(Also cleaned comment.)